# Finding the regular expression

Tags: automata, regular-expressions

I have the problem below:
I need to find the regular expression of the set of strings where $n(a)+n(b)$ is an even number (where $n(a)$ is the number of $a$'s and $n(b)$ is the number of $b$'s) ..

I know that $n(a)$, $n(b)$ must be or both even or both odd in order to get an even sum and I have also found that
$L_1= b^* (ab^* ab^* )$ is the language of even $a$'s,
$L_2= a^* (ba^* ba^* )$ is the language of even $b$'s
but I don't know how to find their intersection..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A$ be the alphabet. If $A = \{a,b\}$, then $n(a) + n(b)$ is simply the length of the word. Therefore your language is the set of words of even length and $(AA)^*$ is a simple regular expression for it.

If $A$ has more than two letters, then a regular expression for your language is $\bigl(C + (a+b)C^*(a+b)\bigr)^*$, where $C = A - \{a,b\}$.

Answer (score 0):

The a's and b's can appear in any order, but the total number of them has to be even. Hint: Think of generating a *pair* of letters at a time, then do this repeatedly.

Comment: how about (aa+ab+ba+bb)* ?

Comment: That will do it! (assuming + represents 'or').

Comment: yes that is what I mean.. thank  you!